# FOSElasticaBundle: Is required to persist entities in other databases?

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, doctrine, foselasticabundle

I'm using Elasticsearch in my job, and I'm considering to connect with Elastic using FOSElasticaBunble as an intermediate abstraction layer.

But I have a doubt, reading the documentation, it seems that is possible to map types to Doctrine Entities, but it also seems that is required to combine Elasticsearch with another persistence layer, like a SQL DB, or MongoDB.

Is possible to use Doctrine Entities without any extra persistence layer aside from Elasticsearch?

Thanks for your attention.